# Http request to Node hangs and resumes only after hitting the a key on the server console

Tags: node.js, http, request, couchdb

I am new to Node and CouchDB need help.

I have created a server written in node.js. This server talks to CouchDB and I am using the cradle module to handle the database operations. I have also used the journey module to route the urls.

I have hosted this server on a windows machine with log messages sent to console (MS DOS prompt) using `console.log()` function.

The server runs fine, but for sometimes, intermittently, the client requests hangs and nothing happens after that. Only when I hit some key on the console all the requests submitted after the hung situation process without any problem.

I am not able to understand why this happens. Is this problem because of some connectivity issues? If so is this anything to do with cradle.js?

Any help or pointers please...

Comment: Can you paste your code also.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**console.log()** is a blocking call. The more you log, the more likely you'll get lag from the server while it writes data to the console.

You can use a non-blocking logger like the one provided by [Sencha Connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html)